# Referencing filter items in ORM with Flask, SqlAlchemy and Jinja2

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, jinja2

I am using Flask to display some data I collected from an API.  It is in the form of beverages, and I already have a SQLlite database containing all of the data.

The information is stored in three models, these being Recipe, Ingredient and Flavour

```
class Recipe(Base):
    """"""
    __tablename__ = "recipes"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(200), index=True, unique=True)
    url = Column(String(200), index=True)
    length = Column(String(120), index=True)
    ingredients = relationship('Ingredient', backref='recipes', lazy='dynamic')
    flavours = relationship('Flavour', backref='recipes', lazy='dynamic')

    def __init__(self, name, url, length):
        """"""
        self.name = name  
        self.url = url
        self.length = length

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Recipe %s>' % (self.name)


class Ingredient(Base):
    """"""
    __tablename__ = "ingredients"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(200))
    quantity = Column(String(200))
    unit = Column(String(200))
    recipe_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('recipes.id'))

    def __init__(self, name, quantity, unit):
        """"""
        self.name = name
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.unit = unit 

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Ingredient %s>' % (self.name)

class Flavour(Base):
    """"""
    __tablename__ = "flavours"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    recipe_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('recipes.id'))
    piquant = Column(String(200), index=True)
    sour = Column(String(200), index=True)
    salty = Column(String(200), index=True)
    sweet = Column(String(200), index=True)
    bitter = Column(String(200), index=True)
    meaty = Column(String(200), index=True)

    def __init__(self, piquant, sour, salty, sweet, bitter, meaty):
        """"""
        self.piquant = piquant 
        self.sour = sour
        self.salty = salty
        self.sweet = sweet
        self.bitter = bitter
        self.meaty = meaty

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Flavour %s>' % (self.recipe_id)
```

I'm basically attempting to render data using Flask templates, and have done so successfully with querying the name of a recipe.  However I am attempting now to query an ingredient, and render on a webpage all of the Recipes containing that ingredient.

In the Python shell, I have successfully queried the Recipe and Ingredient databases to return all Recipes containing the queried ingredient...

```
session.query(Recipe, Ingredient).filter(Recipe.id==Ingredient.recipe_id).filter(Ingredient.name.contains("gin")).all()
```

and it works great, returning an output similar to this:

```
(<Recipe Gin Rickey>, <Ingredient gin >), (<Recipe Gin Gimlet>, <Ingredient gin >)
```

Basically, I would like to render just the Recipe model info on the page, not just the Ingredient model info.

```
@app.route('/search/ingredient/<query>')
def searchingredient(query):

    recipe = session.query(Recipe, Ingredient).filter(Recipe.id==Ingredient.recipe_id).filter(Ingredient.name.contains(query)).all()

    title = "Gin"

    return render_template('query.html', recipes=recipe, title=title)
```

And being new to Flask and Jinja, I have no idea to render this on the html page to include recipe name, recipe url, recipe ingredients, recipe flavours.  I got this far, but it really does not work...

```
<html>
    <head>
        {% block head %}
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - My Application</title> 
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
<body>
{% block body %}
    {% if recipes %}
        {% for recipe in recipes %}
                {{ recipe['name'] }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

If anybody could point me in the right direction, it would be wonderful.  I can supply further info as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query, while it may work, is not well formed.  You don't need to select the ingredient if you're filtering on it and just want the recipe.  Right now the reason you need to do a tuple unpacking is because you're getting a list of 2-tuples as the results (Recipe, Ingredient pairs).  Instead, select just the recipe and join on the ingredient relationship.

```
recipes = session.query(Recipe).join(Recipe.ingredients).filter(
    Ingredient.name.contains('gin')
).all()
```

Or, slightly less efficiently, but more clearly, you can filter on the relationship directly.

```
recipes = session.query(Reciope).filter(
    Recipe.ingredients.any(Ingredient.name.contains('gin'))
).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix to this problem for now

```
{% for key, value in recipes %}
    {{ key.name }}
    {{ key.url }}
{% endfor %}
```

I didn't realise key and value pairs can be used in this way within Jinja.  The output of this is:

```
Gin Rickey http://www.foodrepublic.com/2012/06/28/gin-rickey-recipe Gin Gimlet http://www.marthastewart.com/345584/gin-gimlet
```

And so on.